# Count total with two criterias using Lodash

Tags: javascript, json, nested, underscore.js, lodash

I can't figure out how I can count the total devices based on location and unique serial number.

```
{
"dates": [
    {
        "date": "Sep 1, 2014",
        "devices": [
            {
                "model": "Canon",
                "location": "Chicago",
                "serialNum": "abc123"
            },
            {
                "model": "Canon",
                "location": "Chicago",
                "serialNum": "xyz456"
            },
            {
                "model": "HP",
                "location": "New York",
                "serialNum": "123456"
            },
            {
                "model": "Brother",
                "location": "Chicago",
                "serialNum": "DEF777"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "Sep 2, 2014",
        "devices": [
            {
                "model": "Canon",
                "location": "Chicago",
                "serialNum": "abc123"
            },
            {
                "model": "Canon",
                "location": "Chicago",
                "serialNum": "xyz456"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "Sep 3, 2014",
        "devices": [
            {
                "model": "Canon",
                "location": "Chicago",
                "serialNum": "xyz456"
            },
            {
                "model": "Canon",
                "location": "Chicago",
                "serialNum": "stu789"
            },
            {
                "model": "Epson",
                "location": "NewYork",
                "serialNum": "123456"
            },
            {
                "model": "Epson",
                "location": "NewYork",
                "serialNum": "555555"
            },
            {
                "model": "HP",
                "location": "NewYork",
                "serialNum": "987654"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I would like to capture the total number of unique devices per location

```
Chicago - 4
New York - 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is, in a single expression with lodash chaining syntax.  The short version is you get all devices into one massive list, then you group them by location, then for each location eliminate the duplicate ids, then count the devices.

```
_(dates) //Begin chain
    .pluck("devices") //get the device list for each date
    .flatten() //combine all device lists into a master list
    .groupBy("location") //group into an object of {"location": [devices]} pairs
    .mapValues(function (devicesForLocation) { //replaces [devices] with a count of number of unique serial numbers
        return _(devicesForLocation) //Begin chain
            .pluck("serialNum") //get the serial number for each device
            .uniq() //remove the duplicate serial numbers
        .value() //End chain
        .length; // get the count of unique serial numbers
    }) // result is an object of {"location": countOfUniqueDevices} pairs
.value() //End chain
```

The final result is an object of the form:  {"New York": 1, "NewYork": 3, "Chicago": 4}, though you could add another statement to print that out in string form, obviously.

I'd encourage you to run through this step-by-step to see the result of each step and understand what it's doing.

Comment: Retsam, why did you use mapValues rather than just map?

Comment: @devwannabe map always returns an array, but in this case we don't want an array, we want an object; mapValues returns an object with the same keys, but with different values based on the result of the function passed to it.

Comment: So if `var foo = {x:1, y:2}; var plusOne = function(x) {return x+1}`, then `_.map(foo, plusOne)` returns `[2,3]`, and `_.mapValues(foo, plusOne)` returns `{x:2, y:3}`.

Comment: Awesome! Btw, I was playing with your solution. I changed my source data by adding another layer above devices. Now pluck cannot find devices. I was under the impression that pluck will automatically search for devices. Here is my jsfiddle which is failing - http://jsfiddle.net/1gjr6hjv/

Comment: I got it working by adding pluck('locations').flatten() before .pluck('devices') :)