# Count and display number of records per person using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, count, lodash

I am working with a list of timesheets, and I want to display a list grouped by the UserName, with a count of how many timesheets they have submitted.

I'm able to get close by doing this:

```
var collectionSorted = _.chain(timesheets)
      .groupBy("UserName")
      .toPairs()
      .sortBy(1)
      .value();
```

which, when logged, looks like nice pairs that just contain the UserName and an array of timesheets for that user:

```
0 : Array[2]
1 : Array[2]
2 : Array[2] ...
```

Expanded in the console, they look like:

```
0 : "Chester Burnett"
1 : Array[4]
[then follows an array of four timesheet objects]
length : 4
```

My question, then, is how do I count those timesheets, or use that `length:4` property to display:

```
Chester Burnett  4
```

?

I'm quite new to Lodash so the solution may be painfully simple or obvious but to me it's neither.

Also, my question is not too different from [Count total with two criterias using Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677207/count-total-with-two-criterias-using-lodash/25677357), but that solution uses _.pluck, which is not available in Lodash anymore.

(I find a lot of Lodash examples online are hard to learn from for this reason.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to make any assumptions without seeing the original data, but the easiest thing you can do now is:

```
_.chain(timesheets)
      .groupBy("UserName")
      .toPairs()
      .sortBy(1)
      .map(function (pair) {
           return [pair[0], pair[1].length];
       })
      .value();
```

P.S. `_.pluck` in lodash was replaced with `_.map` that accepts a string as an argument. So as comparing to underscore's `_.pluck(array, 'property')` - in lodash it's `_.map(array, 'property')`

Comment: Thanks for a clear description of "map" and its syntax in my real use case. I was trying to use jQuery .each to append the resulting array to my HTML line by line. Using map as above outputs an array that can be read into a div's HTML directly, in one shot.

Comment: And, subsequently discovered that you can format what is returned, like:

return [pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1].length + ' | '];